# Call front end controller action in my observer

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, action

How can I call my custom front-end controller action in my Observer function?
Is dispatch function worked?

```
<?php
    ....
    public function salesOrderSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order_id = $order->getId();
        $state= $order->getStatus();
        //here I can call the action controller
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Why do you want to call the controller's method in the observer?

Comment: I want to create my order in Exact ERP. Exact having redirect URL so

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$controller = Mage::getControllerInstance(
    'The_Controller_Class',
    Mage::app()->getRequest(),
    Mage::app()->getResponse());
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140361/how-to-get-controller-method-in-observer-in-magento)

Comment: can you explain me more about it

Comment: You have a good explanation in the reference link